# How can i make a call from an android app ? I am doing it in Detail Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make a call from my android app (from Detail Activity). I am using this code, there's not any error in it but when i run the app on my virtual device, Call button isn't work.
Kindly help if anyone got this.

Here is my Detail Activity class

```
    package com.example.sj.dgapps3;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected String name;
    Button b;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    //protected String pos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        name = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Name);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(name);

        String pos = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Position);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.position);
        textView1.setText(pos);


        String qual = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Qualification);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qualification1);
        textView2.setText(qual);

        String exp = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Expertise);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expertise1);
        textView3.setText(exp);

        final String con = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Contact);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact1);
        textView4.setText(con);

        String pic1 = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Pic);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int pic = getResources().getIdentifier(pic1, "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(pic);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String phNum = "tel:" + con;
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phNum));
                        //myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
        /*b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                String phone = "tel:" + con;
                in.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
*/
        /*Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override*//*
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String phone = "tel:" + con;
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }*/

                /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }*/


        /*});*/

        /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int res = getResources().getIdentifier(TeamDetails.getPic(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(res);*/


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Detail Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sj.dgapps3/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Detail Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sj.dgapps3/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.sj.dgapps3.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qualification"
        android:text="Qualification:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expertise"
        android:text="Expertise:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:text="Contact:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expertise"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expertise1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/expertise"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qualification1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contact1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qualification1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:onClick="onClickCall"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SMS"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you write Permission(**android.permission.CALL_PHONE**) for call in Manifest

Comment: @VivekaPatel It's written but still nothing happens when i click my button.

Comment: have you tried in device??still not working??because your code is ok.

Comment: unhide your code "myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));"

Comment: i think you should remove this line from xml `android:onClick="onClickCall."` in Java file your call code write in SetOnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));

    try {

        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Do you include this in your Manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line `android:onClick="onClickCall"` in

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Call"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:onClick="onClickCall"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** 
remove  android:onClick="onClickCall" from your layout xml for the button

**or**

**Solution 2:**

to use onclick from xml you should declare a method like this without Listner

```
public void onClickCall(View v) {
    // does something 
}
```

so you should remove this

```
 b.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        String phNum = "tel:" + con;
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phNum));
                        //myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
```

and do this :

```
public void onClickCall(View v) {
    String phNum = "tel:" + con;
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phNum));
                        //myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DetailActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                        startActivity(myIntent);}
```